# why does forward declaration of a shared_ptr type break visibility of explicit instantiations of other templates types with gcc610?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, llvm, visibility

On my macbook, with macports gcc610, with -fvisibility=hidden, I see a strange behavior.

I have a library that uses templates. To prevent users from instantiating these templates, I have moved the template definitions to a separate file. I want to explicitly instantiate the only instances of this template that can exist.

Further, these explicit instantiations need to be exported from a shared object.

Only in GCC, I have found a weird include-order dependency that seems to determine whether or not the explicit instantiation is actually exported from the shared library. Here is my library:

A.h

```
#ifndef __A_h__
#define __A_h__
namespace commons
{
    struct __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) A {};
}
#endif // __A_h__
```

Property.h

```
#ifndef __Property__
#define __Property__
namespace commons
{
    template<typename T>
    class __attribute__ ((visibility ("default"))) Property
    {
    private:
        T member;
    public:
        void set(const T & t);
        const T & get() const;
    };
}
#endif // __Property__
```

Property.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include "Property.h"

// #include "A.h" // adding this lets the Property instance be exported
namespace commons
{
    struct A;
    struct OhNoes
    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> bad; // removing this also lets the Property instance be exported
    };
}
#include "A.h"


//
// boring implementation for template class
//
namespace commons
{
    template<typename T> const T & Property<T>::get() const{return member;}
    template<typename T> void Property<T>::set(const T & t){member = t;}
}

//
// important explicit instantiation
// this type should be DSO visible because Property and A are both visible
//
template class commons::Property<std::shared_ptr<commons::A>>;
```

Exactly as written, compiling with -fvisibility=hidden with gcc I get:

```
cpp_fiddle $ /opt/local/bin/g++-mp-6 @flags.h -dynamiclib -o g.so Property.cpp
cpp_fiddle $ nm g.so | c++filt
0000000000000d74 unsigned short commons::Property<std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A> >::set(std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A> const&)
0000000000000e84 unsigned short commons::Property<std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A> >::get() const
0000000000000e92 T std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A>::~shared_ptr()
0000000000000ef6 short std::__1::(anonymous namespace)::ignore
                 U std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__add_shared()
                 U std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared()
0000000000000ef5 short std::__1::allocator_arg
0000000000000ef4 short std::__1::piecewise_construct
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

With clang I get:

```
cpp_fiddle $ /opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-4.0 -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden -dynamiclib -o c.so Property.cpp
cpp_fiddle $ nm c.so | c++filt
0000000000000da0 T commons::Property<std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A> >::set(std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A> const&)
0000000000000f20 T commons::Property<std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A> >::get() const
0000000000000f30 unsigned short std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A>::~shared_ptr()
0000000000000f50 unsigned short std::__1::shared_ptr<commons::A>::~shared_ptr()
                 U std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__add_shared()
                 U std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared()
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

My gcc flags.h is just:

```
-std=c++14
-fvisibility=hidden
-nostdinc++
-nodefaultlibs
-isystem "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1"
-isysroot "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk"
-lc
-lc++
-lc++abi
-lgcc_s.10.5
-lgcc_eh
```

Adding a `#pragma GCC visibility push(default)` around the forward declaration appears to work, but it still seems to me that the subsequent include of the A.h header with explicit visibility should override the forward declaration anyway.

Can someone explain this difference to me? Thanks!